# How to mock OWNER configuration using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit, owner

I'm attempting to write some unit tests for an app of mine to verify that my class under test is utilizing the app's configured properties.

We're using [OWNER](http://owner.aeonbits.org/) for our properties resolution, and [JMockit](http://jmockit.org/) for our mocking framework.

My class to be tested:

```
public class TestMe {
    private final MyAppConfig config = ConfigFactory.create(MyAppConfig.class);

    public void doStuff() {
        String someValue = config.getSomeValue();
        ...
    }
}
```

and my test class:

```
public class TestMeTest {
    @Tested
    TestMe testMe;

    @Test
    public void doStuffShouldUseTheConfiguredSomeValue(@Mocked ConfigFactory configFactory, @Mocked MyAppConfig myAppConfig) {
        new Expectations() {{
            ConfigFactory.create(MyApp.class); result = myAppConfig;
            myAppConfig.getSomeValue(); result = "foo";
        }};

        testMe.doStuff();

        new Verifications() {{
            myAppConfig.getSomeValue(); times = 1;
        }};
    }
}
```

When I run the test, however, my mocked ConfigFactory.create() does not get called, and JUnit reports:

```
Missing 1 invocation to:
org.aeonbits.owner.ConfigFactory#create("interface MyAppConfig", [])
```

Can someone provide an example of the proper way to mock an OWNER Config object?

Comment: The "proper way" here is to *not* mock anything. Ask yourself, do you need to test that your code uses some configuration property, or that it obtains it in some particular way (ie, by calling some method in a particular class)? As  said in the question itself, it's the first you need; so, mocking is not the solution here.

Comment: @Rogério Can you recommend a better way to test that the code uses a configuration property? I was thinking that the only way to prove that it was using a configuration property was to make sure it asks for the configuration value instead of deferring to a magic string (and what's not in the example is to then check that it used the configured value).